# Mac version control with merge and support

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, version-control, macos

I'm using a trial of Cornerstone and like the product but don't like the fact they have no support.  Meaning, they never answer their email.  I need a source control program that can handle merging through Subversion.  Specifically, merging from a branch back into trunk.  Cornerstone doesn't and from what I've read Versions doesn't either: http://groups.google.com/group/versions/browse_thread/thread/e499755588b0f59b

Can anyone recommend a source control for Mac that does support merging and also has support?

--EDIT--

Based on comments and given that Versions and Cornerstone have such similar feature sets, would the main reason to buy Versions be its support?

Comment: To be clear, you're looking for a Subversion client?  Or just source control in general?

Answer (score 1):

The svn command line program can perform a merge, albeit without the nice GUI interface to help you with it. It's a pretty basic feature.

[svnX](http://www.lachoseinteractive.net/en/community/subversion/svnx/features/) has been around for a while, and is a Cocoa-based app.

You can try [SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com), which is written in Java. Also many text editors such as TextMate support svn operations from within the editor.

There is also an open source OS X client called [SCPlugin](http://scplugin.tigris.org/) but development appears to be rather slow (no Snow Leopard version, for example).

Comment: I'll see if svnX can do the merge.  If I accomplish that, Cornerstone should pick up the changes without much fuss right?  Meaning, if I merge in one source control app and then switch back to another, should things continue jiving?

Comment: svnX tells me it is to old to work with the working copy.  Guess I will try command line.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Versions](http://versionsapp.com/) but I don't think they have support for merging. I could be wrong, The best way to do merging would be to use the command-line.

Comment: The best way to do merging is to dump svn and use git. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[Git](http://git-scm.com/), althought it isn't subversion (but has almost the same functions, with some extras).

Comment: It should be clear from the question (i.e. Mac) that I'm asking for a native app.

Comment: what do you mean by "native"? Git has a Mac version of the system .. http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/

Comment: Is Git online only or can it be installed and used completely offline like Subversion?

Comment: can be offline, if you install the server version.

Comment: That's incorrect, yoda. Git is not client server per se. Git is distributed yet can be disconnected. One of it's primary strengths is that no server is required, ever. Read this: http://whygitisbetterthanx.com/